# Is there a better way to write this working, but extremely ugly, code?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

  NSLog(@"switching views");
  if([viewController isKindOfClass: [UINavigationController class]] &&
     [[[viewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex: 0] isKindOfClass: [SavedViewController class]]) {

      NSLog(@"its a SavedViewController");
      [[[[viewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex: 0] tableView] reloadData];
  }

}
```

Comment: This belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do comments migrate? ^^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just put the reload data call in the viewDidAppear method of the SavedViewController class?

Comment: Good call  on second thought :)

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation would clean up some of the bracket forest, but that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa's big trade off is readability vs conciseness.

You're not that far off from what I would do:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  NSLog(@"switching views");
  if([viewController isKindOfClass: [UINavigationController class]]) {
      id first_view_controller = [viewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
      if ([first_view_controller isKindOfClass: [SavedViewController class]) {
          NSLog(@"its a SavedViewController");
          [first_view_controller.tableView reloadData];
      }  
   }
}
```

Edited:  used dot notation in a couple of places per C. McCall

Edited again:  looks like ObjC does short circuit.

Comment: Objective C and every other programming language I know of short circuits.